# Azure Servicebus competing receivers are picking up locked messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

We have a Topic with Subscriptions with a default LockDuration of 1min, and multiple SubscriptionClients listening to each subscription. For our test purposes, there are 3 clients listening to a single subscription.

SubscriptionClients are created as:

```
Client = new SubscriptionClient(endPoint, topicName, subscriptionName);
```

We put one message on the Topic, which is filtered into the Subscription.

We would expect one of the SubscriptionClients to pick up the message, and the other two clients cannot because it is locked.

What is actually happening, is all three clients are simultaneously picking up the same message, with different DeliveryCounts, and all within the 1minute lock duration.

Is there something wrong with the way we're creating the SubscriptionClient such that the lock is shared between them rather than being exclusive?

Comment: This should not happen. Can you edit your question and include the code for reading the message?

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly two things that could be wrong. And none of those would be the broker but likely the client-side code.

1. `MaxLockDuration` is too short and while one client is still working on the message, the other client(s) receives that same message. You should be able to confirm by looking at the duration of the message processing. If it exceeds `MaxLockDuration` set on the queue, that's it.
2. You're using a message handler with automatic lock renewal and that one is failing to extend the lock. In that case, you would have a message handler error callback raised with the details.

Either way, you could log the errors and share the logs if possible to help with pinpointing what the issue is.